# How coefficients from finite field can form ring of polynomials?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, graph-theory

Let us consider a graph $G(V,E),$ where $V$ is the set of nodes and $E$ is the set of edges.

$\mathbf{x}=[X_1,\ldots,X_r]$ are symbols multicast by source to $|T|$ sink nodes.  Symbols are from $\mathbb F_{2^m}$.

Suppose we have three vectors of coefficients.

$\mathbf{a}=\{a_{i,l}:1\le i \le r, l \in |E|\}$

$\mathbf{f}=\{f_{k,l}: k,l \in |E|\}$ and

$\mathbf{b}=\{b_{t,i,k}: k \in |E|, t \in T\}$ where $T$ is the set of sink nodes.

These vectors form following matrices: 
$\mathbf{A}= (a_{i,l})$, $\mathbf{F}= (f_{k,l})$, and $\mathbf{B}= (b_{t,i,k})$
$\mathbf{F}$ is the adjacency matrix of the graph.

Symbol $Y_l$ on output edge of node is a linear combination of input edge(s) of node, and the overall linear operation is determined by following equation. Output at sink node $t$:

$Y_l = \mathbf{F}Y_k+\mathbf{B}X_i$

Output symbol at sink node is

$Z_t,_i= \mathbf{B_t} Y_k$

A transfer matrix $\mathbf{M}_t$ (square matrix) is formed as follows:
$$\mathbf{M}_t=\mathbf{A}(I-\mathbf{F})^{-1}\mathbf{B}_t^T$$
Entries of $\mathbf{M}_t$ are $a,f$ and $ b$.

Let us assume that the determinant of a transfer matrix is nonzero over a ring of polynomials $$\mathbb{F}_{2}[\ldots,a_{i,l},\ldots,f_{k,l},\ldots,b_{i,t,k},\ldots]$$

My question is that how the values of $a,f$ and $ b$ form the ring of polynomials when are they are coefficients from $\mathbb F_{2^m}$?

Please note that matrix $\mathbf{M}_t$ contains the values in $a,f$ and $ b$. How $det(\mathbf{M}_t)$ can be interpreted as a polynomial in $\mathbf{a,f,b}$ when they are coefficients?

Comment: Please observe how I've edited your question to use MathJax properly.

Comment: What does $l\in|E|$ mean?

Comment: I have edited a bit with equation at each sink node. Variables are $X_r$ actually.

Comment: It is a bit puzzling, indeed. May be you are to treat all those as variables, and the text is leading up to a design criteria guiding the choice of those particular values? Hard to tell without knowing the context. Is this to model the recovery action of a node in a data storage network?

Comment: Well a source node multicast $X_1$ and $X_2$ to all sink nodes and each sink recover both information symbols simultaneously. Its Linear Network Coding and yes it can be thought as data recovery in storage network. Now what I am unable to understand is that coefficients are taken from finite field for linear operation but these coefficients form the ring of polynomials which are entries of transfer matrix $\mathbf{M_t}$. How is it possible that coefficients made ring of polynomials. And finally the degree of $det(\mathbf{M_t})$ is also decided based on these coefficients.